# codeigniter update db with custom_result_object()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I got a codeigniter custom_result_object with this:

```
$user = $this->CI->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email), 1)->custom_row_object(0,'entities\User');
```

and everything looks fine. I can update values with my setters.

Before I'm going to save i check my values with:

```
die(print_r($user));
```

and the values are correct.

I put my object in my update method.

```
$this->CI->db->update('users', $user, "id = ".$user->getId());
```

But the db is not updating. Am I missing something?

Thx!

EDIT:

So by using CI native db-method i can use:

```
public function save($user)
    {
        if($user->getId() == NULL){
            $this->CI->db->insert('users', $user);
        }else{
            $this->CI->db->update('users', $user, "id = ".$user->getId());
        }
    }
```

Edit 2:
After some more checking I can see that it's not setting variables that are protected. CI is able to get the object through getters and setters but not able to save back to DB?

Comment: $this->db->WHERE('id',$user->getId())->update('úsers',$user); tried this?

Comment: Yep. Same problem.

Comment: should get some error .. update function is simple , it updates the records unless there is no record in the $user variable you are sending to this function

Comment: If `$user->getId()` returns NULL then doesn't `$this->CI->db->update('users', $user, "id = " . $user->getId());` also set the id to NULL before the update?

Comment: After some more checking I can see that it's not setting variables that are protected. CI is able to get the object through getters and setters but not able to save back to DB? It's working if I set all the variables to public...

Answer (score 2):

```
 public function saveData($tbl,$data,$update = false,$previewStr = false){

    $set_str = "NO_QUOTES()";

    if(isset($data[$set_str])){
        foreach($data[$set_str] as $set_key => $set_value){
            $this->db->set($set_key, $set_value, FALSE);
        }
        unset($data[$set_str]);
    }


    if(isset($update[$set_str])){
        foreach($update[$set_str] as $whr_key => $whr_value){
            $this->db->where($whr_key." ".$whr_value,NULL,false);
        }
        unset($update[$set_str]);
        if(is_array($update) and count($update) <= 0){
            $update = true;
        }
    }

    if($update == false){
        $this->db->insert($tbl, $data);

        if($previewStr){
            return $this->db->last_query();
        }else{
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }else{
        $result = NULL;
        if(!is_array($update)){
            if(is_array($data) and count($data) > 0){
                foreach($data as $field => $value){
                    $this->db->set($field, $value);
                }
            }
            $result = $this->db->update($tbl);
        }else{
            $result = $this->db->update($tbl, $data,$update);
        }

        if($previewStr){
            return $this->db->last_query();

        }else{
            return $result;
        }
    }
}

public function delData($tbl = false,$where = array()){
    if($tbl !== false){
        return $this->db->delete($tbl, $where);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


public function simpleQuery($query,$return_array = false,$return_single = false)
 {
    $ac = $this->db->query($query);
    if($return_array === false){
        return $ac;
    }else{
        if($return_single === false){
            return $ac->result_array();
        }else{
            return $ac->row_array();
        }
    }
}
```

Use above code in your model and you i am giving you how to update it use below code in your controller you can insert update and delete by above code

```
$result=$this->Products_model->saveData("customer",array("customer_name"=>$name),array("cust_id"));
```

Comment: Thx. But my repository has methods for CRUD and I would like to be able to just send in my objects there. I got them through the custom_result_object method and I want to save the same without any refactoring.